# Simplifying categorical variables with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, kaggle

I'm working with an airbnb dataset on Kaggle:

```
https://www.kaggle.com/c/airbnb-recruiting-new-user-bookings
```

and want to simplify the values for the language column into 2 groupings - english and non-english.

For instance:

```
users.language.value_counts()
en    15011
zh      101
fr       99
de       53
es       53
ko       43
ru       21
it       20
ja       19
pt       14
sv       11
no        6
da        5
nl        4
el        2
pl        2
tr        2
cs        1
fi        1
is        1
hu        1
Name: language, dtype: int64
```

And the result I want it is:

```
users.language.value_counts()
    english    15011
    non-english 459
    Name: language, dtype: int64
```

This is sort of the solution I want:

```
def language_groupings():
    for i in users:
        if users.language !='en':
            replace(users.language.str, 'non-english')
        else: 
            replace(users.language.str, 'english')
    return users

users['language'] = users.apply(lambda row: language_groupings)
```

Except there's obviously something wrong with this as it returns an empty series when I run value_counts on the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 users.language = np.where( users.language !='en', 'non-english', 'english' )
```

Comment: yep, i wanted to post something similar( `users.assign(lang=np.where(users.language == 'en', 'english', 'non-english'))['lang'].value_counts()
` ), but you were faster... ;)

Comment: If its right. please mark as correct. and upvote if you can. and  good luck

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
In [181]: x
Out[181]:
      val
en  15011
zh    101
fr     99
de     53
es     53
ko     43
ru     21
it     20
ja     19
pt     14
sv     11
no      6
da      5
nl      4
el      2
pl      2
tr      2
cs      1
fi      1
is      1
hu      1

In [182]: x.groupby(x.index == 'en').sum()
Out[182]:
         val
False    459
True   15011
```

Comment: thanks @MaxU! this is also useful for something else I wanted to do